# Have NUnit use SetUpFixture from referenced assembly

Tags: nunit

We're trying to use NUnit to doing integration tests, but having some issues with preparing the system for tests. There is some code that needs to be run before the system is ready to be tested. So I figured we could write a `SetUpFixture` that would run this initialization code. This works fine, as long as the class is in the assembly which is being tested. We're probably going to write some 20-30 of these assemblies, however, so I'd like to stick it in some helper project that can simply be referenced into each test assembly. If I do that, NUnit doesn't run the `SetUp` methods, though (I guess it only looks for them within the assembly being tested).

Is there any way of making NUnit aware of this external setup code? I would want to avoid having specialized attributes and finders, since we're a large organization, and people tend to forget the special solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate your "setup helper" object from external assembly in [`SetUpFixture`] of assembly under test using reflection. Something like:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(pathToSetupHelperDll);            
Type setupHelper = asm.GetType("Setup.Helper");
object h  = Activator.CreateInstance(setupHelper); 
MethodInfo m = setupHelper.GetMethod("DoSomething");            
m.Invoke(h, someParameter);
```